# [Liferay]ローカル環境上のMySQLに接続してtableの要素を出力するポートレット

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, framework

JDBCドライバーを用いて、取得した値をjspで表示させようとしていたのですが、
調べたところService Builderを用いて値を取得、表示させる処理が一般的だとわかりました。

service.xmlにテーブル定義情報を設定まではしたのですが、
そこからどのようなことをすればよいのかが、時間を掛けて調べましたがわかりません。

実現するうえで参考になるWebページ等ありましたら教えていただけると幸いです。

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0):

[このあたり](http://www.javaroad.jp/opensource/js_tomcat8.htm)が参考になると思います(ググればたくさん出てきますが...)。

> Service Builderを用いて値を取得、表示させる処理が一般的だとわかりました。

Service Builderは一般的ではないと思います。